# Cordova + Google Maps Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Tags: cordova

I'm making an app with cordova and I followed this tutorial https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Tutorial-for-Windows however I'm getting an error that I can't resolve:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

Can anyone please help me? I'm really new at this..
Thank you

Answer (score -3):

I ran into the same problem. It seemed to be caused by conflicts in the Android build.gradle after installing / removing various plugins. I was able to solve it by reinstalling the android platform, which regenerated the build.gradle:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Be careful with this – it'll remove your /platforms/android directory and any files you may have created in there, like possibly ant.properties or your .keystore file.  You may want to move them somewhere safe before removing android.